# How do I differentiate labels when configuring them in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, configure

Basically, I'm trying to make a list of variables that update themselves each second, but I can only get the last label to update. I'm not too familiar with tkinter and nothing was helping me. I think the main issue is that I've got it in a def, but I don't know any other way, if someone can help me fix my issue, or even help to overhaul the program, that would be very appreciated.

```
import time
import textwrap
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
from pathlib import Path

while True:
    print(textwrap.fill("Please enter the name that you entered for the main document. It must have the exact same characters and is case sensitive.", 70))
    Name = input()
    FileName = Name+".txt"
    P = Path(FileName)

    if P.exists():

        class MyFirstGUI:

            def __init__(self, master):

                with open(FileName, "r") as file:
                    global Points
                    global Item1
                    global Item2
                    global Item3
                    global PPC
                    global PPS
                    global Item1Cost
                    global Item2Cost
                    global Item3Cost
                    read = file.read().splitlines()
                    Points = read[0]
                    Item1 = read[1]
                    Item2 = read[2]
                    Item3 = read[3]
                    PPC = 1 + int(Item3)
                    PPS = int(Item1)*1 + int(Item2)*5
                    Item1Cost = read[6]
                    Item2Cost = read[7]
                    Item3Cost = read[8]
                    Points = int(Points) + int(PPS)

                VarList = [str(Points), str(Item1), str(Item2), str(Item3), str(PPC), str(PPS), str(Item1Cost), str(Item2Cost), str(Item3Cost)]

                with open(FileName, "w") as file:

                    for List in VarList:
                        file.write(List+'\n')

                root = Tk()
                self.master = master
                master.title("Menu")

                self.label = Label(master, text=Points, anchor='w')
                self.label.pack(fill='both', padx=10)
                self.label = Label(master, text=Item1, anchor='w')
                self.label.pack(fill='both', padx=10)
                self.label = Label(master, text=Item2, anchor='w')
                self.label.pack(fill='both', padx=10)
                self.label = Label(master, text=Item3, anchor='w')
                self.label.pack(fill='both', padx=10)
                self.label = Label(master, text=Item1Cost, anchor='w')
                self.label.pack(fill='both', padx=10)
                self.label = Label(master, text=Item2Cost, anchor='w')
                self.label.pack(fill='both', padx=10)
                self.label = Label(master, text=Item3Cost, anchor='w')
                self.label.pack(fill='both', padx=10)
                self.label = Label(master, text=PPC, anchor='w')
                self.label.pack(fill='both', padx=10)
                self.label = Label(master, text=PPS, anchor='w')
                self.label.pack(fill='both', padx=10)

                root.after(1000, self.task)

            def task(self):

                with open(FileName, "r") as file:
                    global Points
                    global Item1
                    global Item2
                    global Item3
                    global PPC
                    global PPS
                    global Item1Cost
                    global Item2Cost
                    global Item3Cost
                    read = file.read().splitlines()
                    Points = read[0]
                    Item1 = read[1]
                    Item2 = read[2]
                    Item3 = read[3]
                    PPC = 1 + int(Item3)
                    PPS = int(Item1)*1 + int(Item2)*5
                    Item1Cost = read[6]
                    Item2Cost = read[7]
                    Item3Cost = read[8]
                    Points = int(Points) + int(PPS)

                VarList = [str(Points), str(Item1), str(Item2), str(Item3), str(PPC), str(PPS), str(Item1Cost), str(Item2Cost), str(Item3Cost)]

                with open(FileName, "w") as file:

                    for List in VarList:
                        file.write(List+'\n')

                self.label.configure(text=Points)
                self.label.configure(text=Item1)
                self.label.configure(text=Item2)
                self.label.configure(text=Item3)
                root.after(1000, self.task)

        root = Tk()
        my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
        root.mainloop()

    else:
        print(textwrap.fill("You didn't enter a valid name, please try again.", 70))
```

Comment: You simply need to give all your Label variables unique names. Right now you've named them all `self.label`. Or, much neater: you could use a container like a list to hold those objects rather than giving them all a name.

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't like it, it keeps saying that <variable> is undefined.

Comment: Basically, I don't understand how to give the labels different names, or any name that'd different from self.label. If someone has any kind of easy explanation or tutorial on it, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to store all your labels, as dictionaries allow for mappings between keys and values. An example of what this might look like for you:

```
self.labels = {} #Creates an empty dictionary
self.labels["points"] = Label(master, text=Points, anchor='w')
self.labels["points"].pack.pack(fill='both', padx=10)
self.labels["Item1"] = Label(master, text=Item1, anchor='w')
self.labels["Item1"].pack(fill='both', padx=10)
#.... rest of labels here
```

Alternatively, you could use a list to store all the labels and access each label with an index. This way, you wouldn't have to pack each label manually after creating it:

```
self.labels = []
self.labels.append(Label(master, text=Points, anchor='w'))
self.labels.append(Label(master, text=Item1, anchor='w'))
self.labels.append(Label(master, text=Item2, anchor='w'))
#.... rest of labels here

for label in self.labels:
    label.pack(fill='both', padx=10)
```

Finally, you could just give your labels different names. This may be the clearest and most direct option:

```
self.points_label = Label(master, text=Points, anchor='w')
self.Item1_label = Label(master, text=Item1, anchor='w')
self.Item2_label = Label(master, text=Item2, anchor='w')
self.Item3_label = Label(master, text=Item3, anchor='w')
self.Item1Cost_label = Label(master, text=Item1Cost, anchor='w')
#.... rest of labels here. Don't forget to pack each one
```

Remember: identifier names can be anything you want (they **dont** have to just be `self.label` with `tkinter`), just as long as they:

- Don't start with a number
- Contain only letters, numbers and `_`'s
- Aren't reserved python keywords/functions (it isn't recommended to override functions, although it is possible.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using a couple of list to manage the variables and update them.

This allows for us to use much less code to make it easy to read through what we are doing.

```
import textwrap
import tkinter as tk
from pathlib import Path

print(textwrap.fill("Please enter the name that you entered for the main document. It must have the exact same characters and is case sensitive.", 70))
Name = input()
file_name = "./{}.txt".format(Name)

if Path(file_name).exists() == True:

    class MyFirstGUI(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self, fn):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self)
            self.title("Menu")
            self.file_name = fn
            self.var_list = []
            self.lbl_list = []

            with open(self.file_name, "r") as file:
                read = file.read().splitlines()
                self.var_list = [read[0], read[1], read[2], read[3], 1 + int(read[3]),
                                int(read[1])*1 + int(read[2])*5, read[6], read[7], read[8]]

            with open(self.file_name, "w") as file:
                for lst in self.var_list:
                    file.write("{}\n".format(lst))

            for i in range(9):
                self.lbl_list.append(tk.Label(self, text=self.var_list[i], anchor="w"))
                self.lbl_list[i].pack(fill='both', padx=10)

            self.task()

        def task(self):
            with open(self.file_name, "r") as file:
                read = file.read().splitlines()
                self.var_list = [read[0], read[1], read[2], read[3], 1 + int(read[3]),
                                int(read[1])*1 + int(read[2])*5, read[6], read[7], read[8]]

            self.var_list[0] = int(self.var_list[0]) + 1 # added this to visuallize some active change.

            with open(self.file_name, "w") as file:
                for lst in self.var_list:
                    file.write("{}\n".format(lst))

            for i in range(9):
                self.lbl_list[i].config(text=self.var_list[i])

            self.after(1000, self.task)


    app = MyFirstGUI(file_name)
    app.mainloop()

else:
    print(textwrap.fill("You didn't enter a valid name, please try again.", 70))
```